# TypeError{ngDebugContext in Angular tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

This unit test

```
 it('should invoke copy method', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(testClipboardService, 'copy');
    linkEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-raised-button')).nativeElement;
    linkEl.click();
    expect(testClipboardService.copy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

it successfully passed but in console I have an **error** which provoked this line:

```
linkEl.click();
```

I don't understand why

> 'ERROR', TypeError{ngDebugContext: DebugContext_{view: Object{def: ..., parent: ..., viewContainerParent: ..., parentNodeDef: ..., context: ..., component: ..., nodes: ..., state: ..., root: ..., renderer: ..., oldValues: ..., disposables: ..., initIndex: ...}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object{nodeIndex: ..., parent: ..., renderParent: ..., bindingIndex: ..., outputIndex: ..., checkIndex: ..., flags: ..., childFlags: ..., directChildFlags: ... etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jacques Can you provide more information?

Comment: Please update the question with the exception details and stack trace. Also some code that you used would be best

Comment: @yurzui Actually, I'm not really sure what causes this at all. I just know that I see it in the logs while my tests are running, and they annoy me. I found this, and a couple other questions on other sites with the same error, but there are no answers. That's why I put a bounty on it.

Comment: You can find the whole description of your error in chrome console

Comment: @Jacques How can we reproduce your issue? Do you have prepared minimal example?

Comment: @yurzui I am not the OP, I have not prepared anything, I just wanted an answer, so I added a bounty to the OPs question. Also, I just figured it out.

Comment: I just had to add NoopAnimationsModule and import it in my test.

Comment: @Jacques Then you can try to answer on this question)

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like the error message is same as here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16821

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to get rid of the error by adding the NoopAnimationsModule to my imports when configuring testbed. Based on what I found, you are probably missing an import when running your tests.

Example:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyAwesomeComponent ],
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule, // I had to add this
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the error also had to do with imports it seems. I used matSort in the function that was called when the button was clicked. When I added:

```
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material';
```

to my spec.ts file the error went away.

Comment: Another time this error appeared because I forget to include one of the functions of a service I used in a function of my component in my mock service.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem is in `spyOn(testClipboardService, 'copy')` which is set after first `fixtures.detectChanges()`. Can you check if you are doing first detectChanges in `beforeEach`? If yes, you should 'take out' all spies before first detectChanges.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error because I forgot to return an observable from a mocked out function that was subscribed to by my code.

e.g. I had

```
identityService = {authenticate: jasmine.createSpy()};
// ... 
// call function that includes code like this identityService.authenticate().subscribe( ...
// ... The error is logged
```

I replaced it with

```
identityService = {authenticate: jasmine.createSpy()};
identityService.authenticate.and.returnValue(
  of({})
);
//... 
// call function that includes code like this identityService.authenticate().subscribe( ...
```